# Difference between two pieces of code in PHP

Tags: php

I'm sorry if I'm asking something too specific, but I'm a beginner in PHP and this is kind of annoying me. I want to make a function to do some data processing and send an e-mail, but when  I put the e-mail function inside another function, it doesn't work. Why does this happen?

This works:

```
if (do some checking) {
    //...
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        echo 2;
    }
} else {
    echo 3;
}
```

This doesn't work (I cut the code out to this, and it still doesn't work):

```
function sendMail($to, $subject, $body) {
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}
//...
if (do some checking) {
    //...
    echo sendMail($to, $subject, $body);
} else {
    echo 3;
}
```

Comment: What value is echoed when `do some checking` is true in the second block you gave?

Comment: Can you try `echo 'RESULT:'.sendMail($to, $subject, $body);` on corresponding line. It's probably output problem.

Comment: Maybe you should turn on your error reporting in your php.ini. Maybe there's an error message that's not being shown.

Comment: Does "it doesn't work" mean that the email doesn't get sent, or that you see different numbers as the result?

Comment: The email wasn't getting sent. It turns out that I was just doing something wrong in my code. Thank you all for trying to help.

Comment: You don't say what `do some checking` is or what it returns. Wild guess- I'll say it's a variable inside the original sendMail function but not visible to the last if/else statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked fine for me.

```
<?php

function sendMail($to, $subject, $body) {
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }   
}

if (true) {
    echo sendMail('some@email.org', 'some subject', 'some body');
} else {
    echo 3;
}

?>
```

I get 1 echoed. So sendMail function definately works.

What **"do some checking"** is resolved to in your script? Check that.

Answer (score 0):

Is the output 1, 2, or 3 when you run your script?

Try the following: (btw, you need to replace 'email@example.com' with a valid email you can check)

```
<?php
function sendMail($to, $subject, $body) {
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}

if (1) {
    $to = "email@example.com";
    $subject = "Message Subject";
    $body = "Message Body";
    echo sendMail($to, $subject, $body);
} else {
    echo 3;
}
?>
```